# Perform count based on value of repeater control for each row C# ASP.NET

Tags: mysql

Apologies if this might sound very useless, but I am pretty new to ASP.NET and C# [editor note: and SQL]. So basically, I have this repeater that I am binding data from an appointments table within my database. I would like to see the total jobs aggregated by the respective Operators (i.e. Row 1 = 'John Smith' 10 jobs, Row 2 = 'Jim Baker' 16 jobs, etc).

I have managed to do a count from the database but it only returns the total jobs (i.e. 26 jobs) and this value is showing next to each of the operators in the rows (i.e. Row 1 = 'John Smith' 26 jobs, Row 2 = 'Jim Baker' 26 jobs, etc.). Is there anyway I can do it better and get it to work?

I will appreciate any help and apologies once again, my programming skills are very basic.

Aspx:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="listWCSummary" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="ConvertedWC" DataValueField="Id" Width="200" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="listWCSummary_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GAUConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="select * from JobWeekTable"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1" style="background-color: #428BCA;">
                        <strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblWeekNo" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label></strong></td>
                    <td class="auto-style1" style="background-color: #428BCA;">
                        <strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDay1" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label></strong></td>
                    <td class="auto-style1" style="background-color: #428BCA;">
                        <strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDay2" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label></strong></td>
                    <td class="auto-style1" style="background-color: #428BCA;">
                        <strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDay3" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label></strong></td>
                    <td class="auto-style1" style="background-color: #428BCA;">
                        <strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDay4" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label></strong></td>
                    <td class="auto-style1" style="background-color: #428BCA;">
                        <strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDay5" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label></strong></td>
                    <td class="auto-style1" style="background-color: #428BCA;">
                        <strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDay6" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label></strong></td>
                    <td class="auto-style1" style="background-color: #428BCA;">
                        <strong>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDay7" runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label></strong></td>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptrSummaryView" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrSummaryView_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbOpName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EngineerName") %>'></asp:Label>


                                </div>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="row" style="background-color: forestgreen; text-align: center;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="AM" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row" style="text-align: center; color: red;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCountAMDay1" runat="server" Text="Count" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="row" style="background-color: green; text-align: center;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="PM" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCountPMDay1" runat="server" Text="Count" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="row" style="background-color: darkgreen; text-align: center;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="EVE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCountEVEDay1" runat="server" Text="Count" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>






                                </td>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```

C#

```
 protected void rptrSummaryView_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GAUConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {


            con.Open();
        Label lblAM1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCountAMDay1");
        Label lblPM1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCountPMDay1");
        Label lblEV1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCountEVEDay1");
        string Day1 = "select Day1 from JobWeekTable where Id='" + listWCSummary.SelectedValue + "'";
        SqlCommand GetFName = new SqlCommand(Day1, con);
        string Firstday = GetFName.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace("00:00:00", "");

        }

        //Day1

        {

            Label lblAM1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCountAMDay1");
            Label lblPM1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCountPMDay1");
            Label lblEV1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCountEVEDay1");



            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                string Day1 = "select Day1 from JobWeekTable where Id='" + listWCSummary.SelectedValue + "'";

                SqlCommand GetFName = new SqlCommand(Day1, con);
                string Firstday = GetFName.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace("00:00:00", "");

                SqlCommand cmdDay1AM = new SqlCommand("select EngineerTable.EngineerName, Count(AppointmentTable.CustomerID) As CountAM from EngineerTable inner join AppointmentTable on EngineerTable.OpId=AppointmentTable.OpId where TimebandId = '1' and Dateconverted = '" + Firstday + "' group by EngineerName, TimebandId", con);
            using (SqlDataReader rd = cmdDay1AM.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    lblAM1.Text = rd["CountAM"].ToString();
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(lblAM1.Text) < 2)
                    {
                        lblAM1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblAM1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }


    }


}

protected void listWCSummary_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindSummaryViewRptr();
    string WeekId = listWCSummary.SelectedValue;
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GAUConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))

    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from JobWeekTable where Id=@ID", con);
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@ID", WeekId);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        con.Open();
        string Day1 = "select Day1 from JobWeekTable where Id='" + listWCSummary.SelectedValue + "'";
        SqlCommand GetFName = new SqlCommand(Day1, con);
        string FirstName = GetFName.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace("00:00:00", "");
    }


}

private void BindSummaryViewRptr()
{
    string WorkWeekId = listWCSummary.SelectedValue;
    string CustomerId = Request.QueryString["Id"];
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GAUConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct EngineerTable.EngineerName from EngineerTable inner join AppointmentTable on EngineerTable.OpId=AppointmentTable.OpId where AppointmentTable.WorkWeek = @WorkWeekId", con);
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@WorkWeekId", WorkWeekId);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))

        {

            DataTable dtBrands = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtBrands);
            rptrSummaryView.DataSource = dtBrands;
            rptrSummaryView.DataBind();

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code and DB schema or entities.

Comment: Sounds like you need to rewrite your query to group by OperatorId.

Comment: So this is the SQL I have used:

"select EngineerTable.EngineerName, Count(AppointmentTable.CustomerID) As CountAM from EngineerTable inner join AppointmentTable on EngineerTable.OpId=AppointmentTable.OpId where TimebandId = '1' and Dateconverted = '" + FirstName + "' group by EngineerName, TimebandId"

I am struggling to get the Operator Id for each of the row items

Comment: Ok. Makes sense that you get the same result for every row - you are selecting count(AppointmentTable.CustomerId), but you're not doing anything that will split customers into groups. Please edit your post to include the query, and also post your schema.

Comment: Yes, it presents the same result, I have updated my post to include my entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my own problem. I used a `<hiddenfield>` to store the EngineerId and then modified the SQL query that runs `OnItemBound` and that solved it. See code below. Got main help from [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Nested-Repeater-Repeater-inside-Repeater-with-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

```
protected void rptrSummaryView_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   If (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {

            string OpId = (e.Item.FindControl("hfCustomerId") as HiddenField).Value;
            Label lblAM1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCountAMDay1");
            Label lblPM1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCountPMDay1");
            Label lblEV1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCountEVEDay1");
```

And the SQL command is:

```
SqlCommand cmdDay1AM = new SqlCommand("select Count(AppointmentTable.TimebandId) as CountAM from AppointmentTable where Dateconverted= '" + FirstName + "' and TimebandId='1' and AppointmentTable.OpId = '"+OpId+"'", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT jobs AS bakerjobs FROM appointments WHERE name = 'jim baker'

SELECT jobs AS johnjobs FROM appointments WHERE name = 'John Smith'

These queries will return the respective job nos based on name field.

Comment: Thanks IriDium, but the select query is meant to be dynamic, as it is supposed to feed the repeater.